# Parent key not found

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm totally stuck in Sql Oracle database.

I'm trying to add in my table Course_section:

```
Insert into Course_Section (CsectionID, MaxCapacity, CourseID, TermID, LocID)
values('14', '10', '2', '1', '1');
```

and

```
Insert into Course_Section (CsectionID, MaxCapacity, CourseID, TermID, LocID)
values('15', '10', '3', '1', '1');
```

When i tried to insert first one it's telling me that parent key was not found.
So i tried to create two rows in my table Course which will have the same CourseID that i will use after but it's not working...

Sorry i'm still a beginner :)

```
Create table Course
(
CourseName Varchar2(100) not null,
CourseID number(6) PRIMARY KEY, 
Credits number(6)
);


Create table TERM
(
TermID number(6) PRIMARY KEY,
Description Varchar2(100) not null
)
;

Create table LOCATION
(
LocID number(6) PRIMARY KEY,
Building Varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
Room Number(4)
)
;

Create table Student 
(
StudID number(6) PRIMARY KEY, 
Sname Varchar2(100) NOT NULL, 
Birthdate DATE
)
;


Create table Enrollment 
(
StudID number(6) PRIMARY KEY, 
CSectionID number(6), 
FOREIGN KEY (CsectionID) references Student (StudID),
GRADE number(2)
)
; 


Create table Course_Section 
(
CSectionID number(6) PRIMARY KEY, 
MaxCapacity number(3) NOT NULL, 
CourseID number(6),
FOREIGN KEY (COURSEID) REFERENCES COURSE (COURSEID), 
TermID number(6), 
Foreign Key (TERMID) references TERM (termID),
LocID number(6),
Foreign Key (LocID) references Location (locID)
)
;

Insert into COURSE (CourseName, CourseID, Credits)
values('Base de données', '1', '3');
```

Comment: you should remove quotes around values for courseid and creedits in Course table as they are declared as Number. you should do it similarly in other insert statements as well

Comment: @vkp - good observation, but that's not the problem. Oracle will do its best to convert the character string given to match the type of the destination column. In this case there's another issue - see my answer below.

Comment: yes i saw the exact problem mentioned in your answer after commenting. values in his insert may have flipped over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a row in the `COURSE` table whose `COURSEID` has a matching row in the `COURSE` table. To make this work  you'll need to create a row in the `COURSE` table for `COURSEID` 2 and 3:

```
INSERT INTO COURSE (COURSENAME, COURSEID, CREDITS)
  VALUES ('ORGANIC CHEMISTRY', 2, 4);

INSERT INTO COURSE (COURSENAME, COURSEID, CREDITS)
  VALUES ('INORGANIC CHEMISTRY', 3, 5);
```

You'll also need to commit the transaction which is automatically started when you perform these INSERTs:

```
COMMIT;
```

Best of luck.

## **** EDIT ****

There are other foreign key constraints defined, but due to the fact that none of them are named it's very difficult to figure out WHICH constraints are being violated. I've altered your DDL to include names for each of the constraints:

```
Create table Course
  (CourseName Varchar2(100) not null,
   CourseID number(6) CONSTRAINT PK_COURSE PRIMARY KEY, 
   Credits number(6));

Create table TERM
  (TermID number(6) CONSTRAINT PK_TERM PRIMARY KEY,
   Description Varchar2(100) not null);

Create table LOCATION
  (LocID number(6) CONSTRAINT PK_LOCATION PRIMARY KEY,
   Building Varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
   Room Number(4));

Create table Student 
  (StudID number(6) CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   Sname Varchar2(100) NOT NULL, 
   Birthdate DATE);


Create table Enrollment 
  (StudID number(6) CONSTRAINT PK_ENROLLMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   CSectionID number(6), 
   CONSTRAINT ENROLLMENT_FK1
     FOREIGN KEY (CsectionID) references Student (StudID),
   GRADE number(2)); 

Create table Course_Section 
  (CSectionID number(6) CONSTRAINT PK_COURSE_SECTION PRIMARY KEY, 
   MaxCapacity number(3) NOT NULL, 
   CourseID number(6),
   CONSTRAINT COURSE_SECTION_FK1
     FOREIGN KEY (COURSEID) REFERENCES COURSE (COURSEID), 
   TermID number(6), 
   CONSTRAINT COURSE_SECTION_FK2
     Foreign Key (TERMID) references TERM (termID),
   LocID number(6),
   CONSTRAINT COURSE_SECTION_FK3
     Foreign Key (LocID) references Location (locID));

Insert into COURSE (CourseName, CourseID, Credits)
values('Base de données', '1', '3');

INSERT INTO COURSE (COURSENAME, COURSEID, CREDITS)
  VALUES ('ORGANIC CHEMISTRY', 2, 4);

INSERT INTO COURSE (COURSENAME, COURSEID, CREDITS)
  VALUES ('INORGANIC CHEMISTRY', 3, 5);
```

Now when you attempt to insert your row into `COURSE_SECTION` you can see which constraint is being violated. (In this case it's `COURSE_SECTION_FK3`, meaning that a row is missing in the `LOCATION` table).

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4bc3/1)

Best of luck.

Comment: I still have the same error...I also removed the quotes as stated above. :(

Comment: Ah - but there are other foreign key constraints involved. Since none of the constraints in your original question have names it's rather difficult to figure out which constraint is actually being violated. See the edit to my answer above. Best of luck.

Comment: I understand thank you so much! Usually I named them but i created my code a different way and totally missed this part. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

COURSE_SECTION has three foreign keys: on COURSE, LOCATION and TERM:

```
),
FOREIGN KEY (COURSEID) REFERENCES COURSE (COURSEID), 
TermID number(6), 
Foreign Key (TERMID) references TERM (termID),
LocID number(6),
Foreign Key (LocID) references Location (locID)
).
```

You're only pre-populating one parent table, COURSE, so by a process of deductions it's the foreign key on TERM or LOCATION which is failing.

You need to populate rows in all the parent tables before you can populate the child table.